# What are some of the archive formats for source code distribution?

Tags: open-source, archive, php-ziparchive

I'm building a small collection of different open source packages for some internal testing and using **find** to locate source codes from **wget**-s of the various sites. What are the various archiving formats used for source codes, which I can supply to

```
find ./ -type f -regex ".\(tar.gz\|zip\)$"
```

to locate source archives efficiently...

tar.gz, .zip, .bz2, .gz, .rar, .jar

Answer (score 0):

Well, theoretically, any of the archive/compression formats mentioned on [this wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compression_formats) *could* be used as well as any not listed there. But I think you'll find that for the most part, the types you've listed will be used most. Personally I've only ever used zip files and various tar formats (.tar.bz2, etc) to archive my code.